# 17.04 display configuration

Tags: display, system-settings

Nvidia 4-port video card with 4 identical monitors:
After updating from 16.10 to 17.04 the **Settings**-***Displays*** gives a gray window saying "Could not get screen info". Thus I can not arrange the monitors in software to match the physical configuration (or make any other changes). It worked ok until the upgrade.